# should open one accordion at a time in angular 7

Tags: angular

When I am clicking on any of them, all opens. I want only that to be open what I have clicked.

```
  <div [ngClass]="showDetails?'open-faq-link':''" *ngFor="let faq of questionAnswerDetail"
       style="background: #f6f6f6 !important;">
    <div class="faq-title clearfix" (click)="showDetails = ! showDetails">
      <h3>
            <span class="faq-question">{{faq.Question}}
            </span> <span class="faq-arrow"><i [ngClass]="!showDetails?'fa fa-angle-right':'fa fa-angle-down'"
                                         aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="faq-details" *ngIf="showDetails">
      <p [innerHTML]="trustAsHtml(faq.Answer)"></p>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's because you always use `showDetails` to toggle your accordions.

Comment: Yes it is creating problem. Can you please suggest a way to resolve this and achieve what I want. @pzaenger

Comment: Can you provide a StackBlitz with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: sorry due to certain boundations i am unable to provide. @pzaenger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a boolean, e.g. `showDetails`, to each item of `questionAnswerDetail` to control its visibility. Something like the following example.

In your *component.ts*:

```
questionAnswerDetail = [
  {
    showDetails: false,
    question: 'Question 1',
    answer: 'Answer 2'
  },
  {
    showDetails: false,
    question: 'Question 1',
    answer: 'Answer 2'
  }
];
```

In your *component.html*:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let faq of questionAnswerDetail">
  <button (click)="faq.showDetails = !faq.showDetails">{{faq.question}}</button>
  <ng-container *ngIf="faq.showDetails">
    <p>{{faq.answer}}</p>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks I was thinking about the same. i got the clarity now.

Comment: Glad, I could help you :)